# Form with table inside

Tags: html

I am trying to get a specific price for each order size, for instance if my meal is a burger, with small, medium, and large options, I want a price to come up whenever a size is selected. The table is inside of the form, I just do not know what kind of code to use.

I have already tried having each price be a selectable option, however I do not care for the layout.

```
<form method="get" action="#">
    <table>
     <caption> Online Order </caption>
     <thead> 
      <tr>
       <th scope="col" > Dish: </th>
       <th scope="col" > Price </th>
       <th scope="col" > Order Amount </th>
      </tr>
     </thead>

     <tbody>
     <tr>
         <td> 
            Biscuits and Gravy 
            <select name="bg" id="bg" > 
                <option> Small </option>
                <option> Medium </option>
                <option> Large </option>
             </select>
         </td>
         <td> ??? </td>
         <td> <input name="restr" id="restr" type="number" min="1" max="10" /> </td>
     </tr>
```

Comment: You will have to use `javaScript` or related language to display dynamic pricing.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way. Hard-code everything and show/hide prices depending on the selection.

```
<!--call a function when the selection changes (onchange event).-->
<select name="bg" id="bg" onchange="showItem(this)">
    <option selected> Select an option </option>
    <option> Small </option>
    <option> Medium </option>
    <option> Large </option>
</select>
<div>
    <span id="sm" style="display: none;">$2</span>
    <span id="md" style="display: none;">$3</span>
    <span id="lg" style="display: none;">$4</span>
</div>

<script>
    function showItem(ele) {
        // check the selected text, show the related price and hide the others.
        if (ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].text === "Small") {
            document.getElementById("sm").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("md").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("lg").style.display = "none";
        }
        if (ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].text === "Medium") {
            document.getElementById("sm").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("md").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("lg").style.display = "none";
        }
        if (ele.options[ele.selectedIndex].text === "Large") {
            document.getElementById("sm").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("md").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("lg").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```